# C++ classes hierarchy design choice

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In my simulation I have different objects that can be sensed in three ways: object can be seen and/or heard and/or smelled. For example, Animal can be seen, heard and smelled. And piece of Meat on the ground can be seen and smelled but not heard and Wall can only be seen. Then I have different sensors that gather this information - `EyeSensor`, `EarSensor`, `NoseSensor`.

Before state: brief version [gist.github.com link](https://gist.github.com/avasilkov/08b1dfb72a161839501a)

Before I started implementing NoseSensor I had all three functionality in one class that every object inherited - `CanBeSensed` because although classes were different they all needed the same `getDistanceMethod()` and if object implemented any `CanBeSensed` functionality it needed a senseMask - flags if object can be heard/seen/smelled and I didn't want to use virtual inheritance. I sacrificed having data members inside this class for smell, sounds, `EyeInfo` because objects that can only be seen do not need smell/sound info.

Objects then were registered in corresponding Sensor.

Now I've noticed that Smell and Sound sensors are the same and only differ in a single line inside a loop - one calls float `getSound()` and another `float getSmell()` on a `CanBeSensed*` object. When I create one of this two sensors I know what it needs to call, but I don't know how to choose that line without a condition and it's inside a tight loop and a virtual function.

So I've decided to make a single base class for these 3 functionality using virtual inheritance for base class with `getDistanceMethod()`.

But now I had to make my SensorBase class a template class because of this method

`virtual void sense(std::unordered_map<IdInt, CanBeSensed*>& objectsToSense) = 0;`

, and it meant that I need to make `SensorySubSystem` class(manages sensors and objects in range) a template as well. And it meant that all my SubSystems like VisionSubSystem, HearingSubSystem and SmellSubSystem inherit from a template class, and it broke my SensorySystem class which was managing all SensorySubSystems through a vector of pointers to `SensorySubSystem` class `std::vector<SensorySubSystem*> subSystems;`

Please, could you suggest some solution for how to restructure this or how to make compiler decide at compile time(or at least decide once per call//once per object creation) what method to call inside Hearing/Smell `Sensor`s.

Comment: Are you likely to add more types of sensor to the system in future?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Well, maybe. Are you suggesting to make all my subsystems into member variables instead of keeping them in one array?

Comment: I was thinking if there are only 3 senses and you're not likely to add any more then there's nothing wrong with having 3 virtual functions in your base `CanBeSensed` class and having objects that can't be sensed by a particular sense implement it by returning nothing.

Comment: And yes, also your `SensorySubsystem` may as well have the sensors as member variables.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Well, making them member variables(subsystems in system class) will force me to add 300*4*50=60000 additional if conditions per second. I'm talking about checks for nullptr every subsystem variable(4 pc right now per SensorySystem), because I don't know number of subsystems in particular animal. If I got you right.

Comment: They're all quantities though, aren't they? It seems correct to me that an object that makes no sound returns 0.0f  from `getSoundAmplitude()` rather than being a fundamentally different object from one that does make a sound.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst No, I'm not talking about that, I'm talking about SensorySystem which has SubSystems which have Sensors in them. If I go with templates and making subsystems member variables. (Here's whole SensorySystem code https://gist.github.com/avasilkov/deb475360a221a7c3212 (it's short)) Also if object can't be heard it doesn't register with the HearingSubSystem at all. So there is no problem there.

Comment: Is your concern that you can't have a vector of pointers to a objects of a template class? You can if you derive the template class from a non-template class and then make the vector be of pointers to objects of that non-template base class.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Well, actually it is my concern and I thought it would make my code/design even worse than it is. I've been googling this whole thing for two days, I stumbled upon this solution as well.., before deciding to ask here. But thank you, I think I will go with that for now or composition if I think of a way to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your original design I have a few comments:

- The class design in hierarchy.cpp looks quite ok to me.
- Unless distance is something specific to sensory information getDistance() doesn't look like a method that belongs into this class. It could be moved either into a Vec2d-class or to a helper function (calculatePositon(vec2d, vec2d)). I do not see, why getDistance() is virtual, if it does something different than calculating the distance between the given position and the objects position, then it should be renamed.
- The class CanBeSensed sounds more like a property and should probably be renamed to e.g. SensableObject.

Regarding your new approach: 
Inheritance should primarily be used to express concepts (is-a-relations), not to share code. If you want to reuse an algorithm, consider writing an algorithm class or function (favour composition over inheritance).

In summary I propose to keep your original class design cleaning it up a little as described above. You could add virtual functions canBeSmelled/canBeHeard/canBeSeen to CanBeSensed. 
Alternatively you could create a class hierachy:

- class Object{ getPosition(); }
- class ObjectWithSmell : virtual Object
- class ObjectWithSound : virtual Object
- ...

But then you'd have to deal with virtual inheritance without any noticeable benefit.
The shared calculation code could go into an algorithmic class or function.

Comment: About getDistance. The thing is that the current center of an object is calculated inside it. The actual distance is calculated quite easily. http://pastebin.com/Qgtv2HEJ . Hm, then getPos is code duplication I guess, hah. And thank you for your comments, my design is bad I think from the day one. And I'm here because of it. Could you elaborate more on how to apply composition in my case? I've stumbled upon inheritance being not for code reuse and composition thing, but couldn't get my head around how to apply it here. A push with a little concrete example will help a lot.

Comment: The thing is, I would go with my new approach with virtual inheritance, then in CanBeHeard/Smelled I will rename getSound/getSmell  to the same name and my Ear/Nose sensors will be templated guys and one function call at line 50 will resolve itself.But the problem is that then I need templated subSystems that will destroy my SensorySystem array of pointers to a SubSystem base class.

Comment: Don't make things overly complicated, I do not think your original design is bad. What is the code duplication you are worried about? Could you post your code after the redesign?

Comment: In truth I haven't done redesign. Virtual inheritence will force me to use templates and templates will force me to create another untemplated base class for SensorySubSystem(because of the vector in SensorySystem) which will provide virtual functions that templated version will redefine and will use to call its templated version of this virtual function. I think it's too many virtual functions already. May be I don't get something, don't know. for now, I just... copied whole Ear class code into Nose class and use old design. http://i.imgur.com/YsV3BDs.png

Comment: Starting from your example, it seems that you could move a lot of code from your specific sensor classes to SensorBase. You could than just implement the "sense"-Method in the base class (see http://pastebin.com/03ekrcq7).

Comment: It adds virtual function call of another virtual function(version without templates - current- has getSmell/Sound as virtual functions) inside a tight loop. Worst case scenario (3*2+4*2)*8*300*50 calls per second or even worse. The thing is, there is Vision sensor which works differently from Ear or Nose. It requires EyeInfo object instead of float. Initially I thought that Ear and Nose would get SmellInfo and SoundInfo objects. It's only recently that I changed them into simple floats. That's why I'm saying that my design is bad ;) I should probably read at least one OOP book..........